# Debugging help- rules are getting fired multiple times (recursively) when they should not be

Tags: 7, rules

I'm running Drupal 7 with Rules 2.0.  I also tried the latest dev version (March 08) and I'm running into the same problem.

I have two rules that are set to run whenever a user account is updated.  Each rule should only be executed once per account update.  The "Activate- Lex" rule behaves properly; however, the "Activate-Friends" rule executes twice.  Both rules are nearly identical in structure except for the fields that they check.

In the Rules evaluation log, I see "Reacting on event- After updating a user account" and both rules fire once.  Then, near the bottom there is an additional entry for "Reacting on event- After updating an existing user account" and under this entry the "Activate- Friends" rule fires again but for "Activate- Lex" there is this message: "Not evaluating reaction rule Activate- Lex to prevent recursion."

How can I prevent "Activate- Friends" from also being fired recursively?

I am including the rules below.

"Activate- Friends" fires twice:

```
{ "rules_activate_friends" : {
    "LABEL" : "Activate- Friends",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "TAGS" : [ "profile_management" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "user_update" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "account-unchanged:field-acc-friends" ], "value" : 1 } },
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "account:field-acc-friends" ], "value" : 1 } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "component_rules_activate_friends_features" : { "acc_to_add_friends" : [ "account" ] } }
    ]
  }
}
```

While "Activate- Lex" fires only once (correctly):

```
{ "rules_activate_lex" : {
    "LABEL" : "Activate- Lex",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "TAGS" : [ "profile_management" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "user_update" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "account-unchanged:field-acc-lex" ], "value" : 1 } },
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "account:field-acc-lex" ], "value" : 1 } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "component_rules_activate_lex_features" : { "acc_to_add_lex" : [ "account" ] } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the components.  It turns out that the "Activate Friends" rule component only had a heartbeat "Log Activity" action, which was the source of the problem.